# My Nvidia 540m graphics card stopped responding error

Tags: windows-7, freeze, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-graphics-card

I got a problem with my Nvidia 540m 2gb graphics card. Whenever i play any game, (after a while) my laptop freezes and the game exits with a notification that "Nvidia graphics kernel sttoped responding and has been recovered" . I tried - formating my computer and reinstalling windows, tdrdelay method, installing lestest graphics driver, changing rams, high performance mode, through cleaning of inside of my laptop but nothing seems to be working. Also i have noticed that when I play games DISABILING my Nvidia graphics card (my laptop has dual gpu ie on intel hd graphics 3000 2gb) it works without any errors or freezing. I have Dell XPS L502X laptop. Can anyone please advise me what should I do to cure this error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've done most forms of diagnostics. If the issue is persisting beyond a clean installation and latest driver installation, this points more towards a hardware issue of some form. If you can remember a point where the device worked without a problem, it may be worth using an older driver just to completely eliminate a software cause.

It's worth keeping an eye on the temperature of the GPU with some form of monitoring software (The first that comes to mind is [GPUTemp](http://www.gputemp.com/)) to see if there's a link between the temperature and when it crashes.

If there is a link and the temperatures are getting particularly high, I realise you have said you've cleaned it but it may be worth opening the machine and making sure air can flow properly. The heatsinks may need clearing, then fan may need replacing. I've also seen cases where heatpipes have failed and don't transfer heat correctly, and replacing the block with the heatpipes can resolve overheating issues. Finally, it could be a bad contact with the GPU itself, and replacing the thermal pad may be beneficial.

If temperature *isn't* the issue, it's likely the GPU itself is failing. Depending on the laptop, this may be replaceable, but looking at [this thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19384094) gives a fairly swift indication that this isn't possible. As such, you could find out from Dell what it would cost to repair this, if the machine is outside of it's warranty period.

Comment: I have throughly cleaned my laptop (every possible dust collecting component) but the problem still presist. But my laptop does heats up during heavy gaming. Thx Jonno for your interest in my question.

Comment: @KartikPillai It's worth monitoring the temps so you can see if it is raising particularly quickly. Realistically I'd expect it to attempt to throttle performance before it actually crashed. I think you may be looking at the beginnings of a faulty GPU.

Comment: I've even tried installing old driver which I got with my Dell driver DVD. But same

Comment: Ok i will monitor my gpu temperature and inform u soon

Comment: I used gputemp to find out at what temperature my game crashes and I found out that it occurs when the gpu (Nvidia) temperature goes up to somewhere above 80°C (as 80°C is gputemp's max temperature i cant say the accurate temperature)

Comment: Hey,  I just found out that when I unplugg my charger (During the crash *audio repeating phase of crash*)of my laptop it recovers from the crash! Also when I play on battery it doesn't crash. Is my charger here faulty?